# SQL Server database size limit on Azure, what to do?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

This may be a question that is from my lack of infrastructure knowledge as a software developer.

I am developing a platform to store application data logs. Simple stuff so far. There is a SQL Server database that will have a table called logs, and each row will be the log tied to the user that saved that log. This is going to be using Azures SQL database.

Ongoing, imagine I have 10,000 users, the limits of the database will be reached (250gb, or even 1TB eventually).

One obvious answer is to purge old data. However this isn't really the answer if that data is needed at all times. I guess this is not really a question specific to the log application above, its generally what to do when your database gets too large to be held by one database.

I hear all the time about horizontal scaling, especially with NoSQL databases. However, I need to know where to go and what to research/learn. When you work as a developer, you learn how to write applications, not necessarily how to scale them, and I need to know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could consider Azure Table Storage for this purpose instead of a SQL database.
It's a pretty basic and easy to use NoSQL option, and since you seem to be using Azure anyway, might be worth looking into.
Here's the [Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables) page from the Azure docs.

Comment: Table Storage is a completely different type of data store, with different query capabilities. They are not swappable. And... this doesn't solve the OP's question.

Comment: Table Storage might solve the OP's _real_ problem - storage space.

Comment: Without knowing how the OP will be querying, that's not necessarily true. The OP will have more challenges with date-range queries (or querying on any property that's not a partition key or row key). And will have challenges using a SQL Server specific reporting tool.

Comment: Also, the OP hasn't talked at all about *what* needs to be queried. If it's just logs, is it really necessary to have all logs accessible, or only recent logs? If the latter, the OP could archive logs (in table storage or blob storage, for example), where it's accessible but not queryable.

Comment: In this particular case, its more a general SQL question. The decision to go for SQL over Table Storage is not really the point of the question, although as @DavidMakogon mentioned, its down to querying flexibility

Answer (score 0):

Have a read around [SQL Server Stretch Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/sql-server-stretch-database/). It might be what your after.

Comment: This is definitely good to know, but still has a limit of 240TB. If each customer has 1gb of logs a day, 30 day retention, and 10,000 customers, thats the limit hit. Although that level of usage and customer base is theoretical and unlikely, its still possible

Comment: Reading this article it extends to 1PB https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-service-capacity-limits e.g.  This space is independent of tempdb or log space, and therefore this space is dedicated to permanent tables. Clustered columnstore compression is estimated at 5X. This compression allows the database to grow to approximately 1 PB when all tables are clustered columnstore (the default table type).

Comment: If you could split it over multiple DBS then you would get around the limitation

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, for SQL Server, you have three choices--

- scale vertically
- scale horizontally
- purge/archive old data

Scaling vertically means getting a bigger server with more capacity. In Azure, this means paying for the next size up until it runs out of space.

Horizontally scaling means getting multiple servers and distributing the data. For something like logging, you could create a new database every year, and know which database to send your query to based on date range; for example.

Purging or archiving old data is a decent option for real-world scenarios, because you likely don't need log files going back 30 years.  You would dump your data to something more cost effective for archive, and keep your SQL Server data loaded with only relevant data (e.g. the past several years of logging).

Comment: Purging old data is definitely something that will be done here, however as mentioned below, even with a 30 day retention limits can be hit quickly. Vertical scaling doesn't really fix the issue, so horizontal scaling is the key it seems. Ideally, I need a solution where I have a single point of communication that I can insert and query, and that hunts out the relevant database

Answer (score 0):

Split it over multiple databases and use elastic query.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview

Or consider using another storage format for logs. As already mentioned, azure tables might be better. See here [Strategy for storing application logs in Azure Table Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605328/strategy-for-storing-application-logs-in-azure-table-storage)

The important thing you haven't mentioned is: how will these logs be queried? By User? By date? Can you identify hot and cold data?

Comment: In the case of the elastic query, will this be seamless? Where my application connects to one source and Azure does all the work to split to various databases? Or will I be responsible for my db inserts to the appropriate database and this provides me the ability to cross query

Comment: I've never implemented it before but I assume so (once you've set up your sharding) I suggest you read the article or you can wait for someone else who knows more than me about it.